# how .setText from controller data class to get data

Tags: android, firebase, model-view-controller

Firebase data is getting into the app it's showing on log cat no problem with that. I want to show that data in the UI it parses data from humidtyContoller to main Activity but I don't know-how setText from another class

```
TextView text_humidity = findViewById(R.id.textHum);
// Write a message to the database

HumiditySensorController humiditySensorController=new HumiditySensorController();
humiditySensorController.getAllHumidityData();
text_humidity.setText( "%");
```

Humidity data accessed from firebase with:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("Weather/Humidity");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(" Value : " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            HumidityData data = new HumidityData(snapshot.getKey(), snapshot.getValue(String.class));
            System.out.println(" Value : " + data.getHumidity());
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is inside your HumiditySensorController? Can you retrieve the humidityData from the main activity?

Comment: humidity is in a humidityController class i want to get that data tom the setText

Comment: Is humidity stored in a member within the HumidityController? Can you do something like this `text_humidity.setText(humiditySensorController.getHumidity() + "%");`?

Comment: i did that not working

Comment: Is your getAllHumidityData function synchronous? If not, you will need to register a callback so you know when the data is available. It is a lot easier to help with these sort of issues if you show us the internals of your controller.

Comment: DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("Weather/Humidity");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             
                System.out.println(" Value : "+dataSnapshot.getValue());
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    HumidityData data=new HumidityData(snapshot.getKey(), snapshot.getValue(String.class));
System.out.println(" Value : "+data.getHumidity());

Answer (score 0):

Because you network requests to firebase are asynchronous you need to add a method of asynchronous communication between your controller and activity. One method of doing this is through a callback interface.

Your controller can receive a listener interface:

```
class HumiditySensorController {
    public interface HumidityDataListener {
        void onDataUpdated(HumidityData humidityData);
    }

    public void getAllHumidityData(HumidityDataListener humidityDataListener) {
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("Weather/Humidity");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                System.out.println(" Value : " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    HumidityData data = new HumidityData(snapshot.getKey(), snapshot.getValue(String.class));

                    if(humidityDataListener != null){
                        humidityDataListener.onDataUpdated(data);
                    }

                    System.out.println(" Value : " + data.getHumidity());
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And your activity can pass a listener, like this:

```
final TextView text_humidity = findViewById(R.id.textHum);        
HumiditySensorController humiditySensorController=new HumiditySensorController();
humiditySensorController.getAllHumidityData(new HumiditySensorController.HumidityDataListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataUpdated(HumidityData humidityData) {
                text_humidity.setText(humidityData + "%");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you put a println in the callback function to ensure it is being called? Add a line before setText in your activity.

Comment: im newbie to android can you do for me

Comment: Sorry mate, that's not what this service is. I can help you with the issue but you'll need to provide some information